# Which spark-sql-kafka to use for Apache Kafka 1.0.0.?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Which spark-sql-kafka .jar as a dependency when running spark-submit should I use for Apache Kafka 1.0.0.?

I use Scale 2.11 and Spark 2.2.1.

I would like to run a Spark Structured Streaming application.

Comment: you can use spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11. with version 2.2.1

Comment: I though so as well, but this jar file doesnt work for me. With this file I get an error `pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: u'Failed to construct kafka consumer\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = 99afe58e-3b05-45f7-af29-3d81b13b2b1a, runId = 4a715b16-9a99-406a-a272-0dfb3e152a7b]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {}\n\nCurrent State: INITIALIZING\nThread State: RUNNABLE'`

Comment: @Erhan, were you able to figure out suitable jar for this?

Comment: @Kaushal Yes, after a painful trial and error session changing multiple different jars due to compatibility issues I found the right setting. I do not have the code anymore though :( Sorry to disappoint you.